# Precalculus - Finding n in exponential equation with x as base

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My nephew is having trouble solving this problem:

> $$(x^{10n})((x^5)(x^{-5})^n))=(x^{-10})$$

I'm unsure as to whether or not I can "cancel out" the $x$ in the bases and rewrite everything as follows:

$$10n*(5*-5^n )= -10$$

I seem to remember this from my GRE practice, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with the n in the exponent and the base in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: hint exponent laws.

Comment: Is the equation $x^{10n} \left( x^5 \left(x^{-5}\right)^n \right) = x^{-10}$? Or is it, perhaps $x^{10n} \left( \left(x^5 x^{-5}\right)^n \right) = x^{-10}$

Comment: The expression on the left hand side has 4 left hand parens and 5 right hand parens, so it's unclear what is being asked.

Answer (score 3):

By the laws of exponents 
$$x^{10n} x^5 \left(x^{-5}\right)^n = x^{10 n + 5 - 5 n} = x^{5 + 5 n}$$
so you want 
$$ x^{5+5n} = x^{-10}$$
Assuming $x$ is not $0$ or $\pm 1$, $x^t$ is a one-to-one function of $t$, so this will
imply $$5 + 5 n = -10$$

Answer (score 0):

When exponents are at the same level you only deal with addition and multiplication... So $x^{10n} \left( x^5 \left(x^{-5}\right)^n \right) = x^{-10}$
Multiply n and 5

$x^{10n}  x^5 x^{-5n} = x^{-10}$

Adding 5 and 5n

$x^{10n} x^{5-5n} = x^{-10}$

$x^{10n+5-5n} = x^{-10}$

$5+5n = -10$

$5n = -15$